# word not showing all the picture

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2011

I have a pig picture that i want to insert vertically

I did that but not all the picture is shown, please look, you can see that the pic is not shown completely from the button (i hope you get me sorry my english sucks), and as you see you can see the new lines signs. could you help please

[image]

I am using this word

[image]

Comment: Is it behind the other image?

Comment: Rather than inserting this image vertically, you can make a new section between the pages that precede and follow the image (`Layout` tab > `Breaks` > Next Page). Then, change the new section's orientation (`Layout` tab > `Orientation` > `Landscape`). Insert your image normally without flipping it.